Ohm’s Law understanding problem
We know that $V$ is directly proportional to $I$ for the same resistance.
That means if we double the voltage, the current gets doubled.
We also know that if a bulb or any other resistor works on a battery of say 2V, the resistor “takes away” 2 Joules of energy per Coulomb charge that passes through it.
Now that we have established what we already know, My question is:
Say there is a circuit, with a battery of 2V, and the current flowing through it is 3A. The resistor present in the circuit is a bulb which by definition of potential difference “takes away” 2 Joules of energy per Coulomb charge that passes through it. If we double the P.D., the current should become 6A, but the bulb is still same!!! It should still only take 2J energy for every coulomb. It’s not like we change the bulb too every time we change Voltage. Therefore the energy for every coulomb charge should increase 2J for every rotation, increasing its energy indefinitely.
I may have the wrong understanding of Ohm’s law so please correct me if I’m wrong.

I assume you got the resistor “takes away” 2 Joules of energy per Coulomb charge using the equation $W = QV$? If so, when you double the P.D., wouldn't you also double the amount of energy taken away by the resistor?

Imagine smashing a car into a wall at 10 mph and at 100mph - it would absorb quite different amounts of energy in the two cases, but it is the same car.

Would you mind clarifying this sentence: "Therefore the energy for every coulomb charge should increase 2J for every rotation, increasing its energy indefinitely."

@Allure Thanks for your reply! I understand your point, but in the relation W = QV, W implies the work done by the battery to a total Of Q charges. So if I double the amount of work done by the battery on each charge, V will also double. But it shouldn’t imply that the resistor will also Double the amount of energy it takes away per charge because of no change in its physical properties.

@Steeven it's saying that every time the charge goes round the circuit the energy goes up (imagine a circuit with battery and bulb only; each time the charge goes out of the positive terminal and into the negative terminal it is one "rotation").

@Roger Thanks for your reply! Yes certainly the wall will absorb all the Kinetic energy of the car, because the car can not pass through the wall. But here using this analogy can cause confusion because electrons can pass through the resistor.

@ArshHussainNaqvi You double the P.D. (i.e. potential difference), which means you double $V$. The work done doubles too, but that's because the potential difference went up. The resistor now dissipates twice as much energy; its physical properties are not the same, it is hotter due to Joule's law.

@Allure that would mean that all the energy of each charge is taken away whenever it passes through a resistor. This is the only logical explanation as when the P.D. Say is 6V, the resistor dissipated 3 times the heat. But this effectively makes the passage of charge through circuits impossible as all their energy is taken away. Not to mention that the series circuits are all the more impossible as the charges loses all their energy passing through the first resistor, leaving none for the other resistors.

@ArshHussainNaqvi if you apply $W = QV$ a second time, this time with the higher potential difference, you get that the higher energy is dissipated. So I don't understand what your question is. In your particular setup, there is also only one resistor.

The energy dissipated per charge $q$ depends only on this charge and potential decrease $V$ on terminals of the bulb: $E=qV$, it does not depend on electric resistance of the bulb. This is like when volume of water $v$ in continuous flow passes through a pipe segment where there is pressure difference on two ends $P$: $E=vP$, it does not depend on resistance of the pipe against the flow. Properties of bulb or pipe only affect rate of energy dissipation in time; the lower the resistance, the greater the flow, and the greater the energy dissipation per unit time.

A close analogy is slides in a children's park: the speed with which a child moves on a slide is the current, the height of the slide is voltage. Now imagine several slides, all of them having the same length, but different angle and hence different height above the ground. For completeness we could imagine that the slides have strong friction, so that a child slides slowly (image source).
Very similar viscous friction models are really used to explain the resistance (they are closely related to Drude model, which has a few additional complications.)
Sliding along the slides also brings us to another important point - not all of the potential energy that electrons have is spent in the resistor - just like not all the energy of the sliding child is wasted on friction - they arrive at the bottom of slides with different speed. The energy that is actually produced in the resistor is given by Joule's law (see here for Drude-like derivation).



Say there is a circuit, with a battery of 2V, and the current flowing through it is 3A.

Sure, we can take this as true.

The resistor present in the circuit is a bulb which by definition of potential difference “takes away” 2 Joules of energy per Coulomb charge that passes through it.

There is no need to quote "takes away" because it is basically exactly correct, at least by the definitions and premises you started out with.

If we double the P.D., the current should become 6A, but the bulb is still same!!!

By this assertion, you immediately imply that the bulb is ohmic, which is a tolerably good approximation / assumption.

It should still only take 2J energy for every coulomb.

This is wrong. It will now take 4J of energy for every Coulomb worth of charge. You are just mistaken in your understanding here.
Worse, originally, it was taking 6W of power, and now it has jumped to 24W of power.

Therefore the energy for every coulomb charge should increase 2J for every rotation, increasing its energy indefinitely.

What rotation? And no, you are wrong.

I'm downvoting because although the answer is correct, it doesn't explain why; it uses phrases like You are just mistaken in your understanding here without giving the correct understanding (and the math behind it)

naturallyInconsistent Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate the effort.


I put quotations on ‘takes away’ because most people don’t consider it as an appropriate statement. They prefer uses/utilises. I did not use these words because I wanted to make people understand the problem completely.


I did not understand how the bulb will now use 4J of energy per Coulomb. Because the bulb is same and there has been no change in its physical properties, shouldn’t it still use the same as before?


By a rotation I meant the trip of a unit charge from one terminal to the other one.



@Allure, the OP probably isn't interested in a standard explanation, which is why I tried to be useful in the sense appropriate for the OP, not the general populace. Not to mention that the maths is way too easy.

@ArshHussainNaqvi 2) The exact same bulb with no change in physical properties will change its amount of energy used per Coulomb; that's what you need to get a new understanding of. Without you stating things to higher detail, we cannot figure out where your precise misunderstanding is. 3) When an F1 race driver finishes one lap of the circuit, do you hear people calling that one rotation?

@naturallyInconsistent Firstly, I would like to apologise for the use of the word rotation. I realise that it can be confusing and Secondly, I would like to discuss on the first line of your reply. This would most certainly solve the issue, but doesn’t it raise more questions? It would imply that the resistor uses all of the energy of each charge making the motion of electrons from one terminal to other impossible as all of their energy would be used. Also the series circuits would become impossible as the electrons wouldn't have any energy left after they pass through the first resistor.

The kinetic energy of the electrons are not being used up at all as they go around a circuit. If you have more than one resistor, the system balances itself out so that all the resistors get their fair share of energy. It is not equal sharing, but rather a sharing that satisfies Ohm's law and Kirchoff's laws everywhere.
